# Visually identify name of field in PDF form

Tags: forms, pdf, fdf

I know some similar issues exist ([Find the field names of inputtable form fields in a PDF document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310533/find-the-field-names-of-inputtable-form-fields-in-a-pdf-document)) but my question is different:

I have all the field names (in fdf file).

I wish I could visually identify directly on the PDF.

With acrobat I should be able to right click on a field and then select "display the name of the field" but I can find no such thing.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: See also: [How to view form field names in a pdf document](https://superuser.com/questions/137227/how-to-view-form-field-names-in-a-pdf-document/)

Answer (score 30):

Ok. I have found pdf editor where this is possible. Probably acrobat pro too...

http://www.pdfescape.com/

Right click on the field : unlock. Right click again : get properties.

Comment: Did you manage to find any other tools that display the names of the form fields inside a PDF document?

Comment: Very awesome Trick Thanks Man

Comment: I don't see unlock, not working for me

Comment: This worked a year ago.  I've come back to this website and it seems like their site has changed and this is no longer possible.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using [Apache PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) to fill the form automatically, you can use it to fill all text fields with their name:

```
final PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(in);
final PDAcroForm acroForm = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
final Iterator<PDField> it = acroForm.getFieldIterator();

for (PDField f : acroForm.getFields()) {
    System.out.println(f.toString());

    if (f instanceof PDTextField) {
        f.setValue(f.getFullyQualifiedName());
    }
};

document.save(...);
```

When you open the generated PDF, you'll be able to identify each field immediately like you asked.

[image: example]

Comment: How does this ***Visually** identify name of field in PDF form*? Which is what the OP asked for after all...

Comment: Well when you open the output PDF, every text field is filled with its name, so just by looking at a field you can see (and copy) its name.

Comment: Arg, right, sorry, I missed your actual proposal. You're right, that indeed is a way. There are some forms and fields it won't for (check boxes, too small fields, forms with javascript clearing fields on view start,...) but for many it will.

Comment: I am not too familiar with java, could you show how to get this result?

Answer (score 4):

There's a free tool that does this job quite well.

```
sudo apt install pdftk
```

You can use pdftk's `dump_data_fields` to get all fields like this:

```
pdftk sample.pdf dump_data_fields output fields.txt
```

Dump would look something like this:

```
FieldType: Text
FieldName: CRIssue
FieldFlags: 8388608
FieldValue: Issue with something ---- if it is filled
FieldJustification: Center
```

---

If you're looking for a tool where you can load your editable pdf file, click on the input (text or checkbox) field and get the basic info like Name:     https://code-industry.net/masterpdfeditor/. It's available cross-platform.

Comment: Yes but they are not visually located in the pdf like I asked.

Answer (score 1):

I found this website which will allow you to upload a pdf, visualize that pdf, click on any fillable field of this pdf, and see all the properties of that field including its name.

Here's that website: https://extract-fillable-fields.pdffiller.com/

You'll have to click on the green tabs on the right with the label `EDIT FILLABLE FIELDS` to see those fields details.