# Visually show field names in a fillable PDF

Tags: pdf, pdftk

I have a fillable PDF. I would like to know the names of the fields in it. I know I can find this out using pdftk and the dump_data_fields flag. However, it is a painful process to match the fieldname to the actual field in the PDF.

Is there a tool out there that shows the real PDF and the fieldnames over it?

Comment: Answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38257142/visually-identify-name-of-field-in-pdf-form Use PDFEscape online

Answer (score 0):

When Adobe Acrobat Pro is put into Form Authoring mode, it will show the form fields with their name overlayed.